# Remove link before another link

Tags: redirect

I got some problems at that website . When I try to submit my links is : yyy.com . It will auto get http://xyzz.com/http://yyy.com . I try to use ../../ and ; %00 but it can't .

I can't edit code or anything . I only can submit text or link . Thanks you !

Comment: Are you sure the link is `http://yyy.com` and not `yyy.com`?

Comment: sorry , if I enter yyy.com it will be yyy , http://yyy.com it will be http://yyy.com

Answer (score -1):

start your link like this:

```
http://
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: Yes , When I try to enter http:// it will be 
http://xyzz.com/http://yyy,com

Comment: May you please share how you try to do with all code? You might be doing something wrong.